# Pass subreport variable to other subreport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I want to pass already calculated variable from the first subreport (variable is defined is the master report) and pass it to the second subreport of the master report.

I already tried but in the second subreport I always get null value.

Please help!

Comment: I am afraid you can't do that due to Jasper limitations. Only solution that comes to my mind is calculationg the variable in the master report/

Comment: How can I then calculate variable in the master report which depends on the result of the query (that query I use in the first subreport)?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [this solution](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=83&forumid=101&topicid=29420). It boils down to using the correct Reset Type for the group the subreport is in. Furthermore make sure you are not using iReport 3.0.0.

Please also make sure you haven't set *Blank when null* as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466233/ireport-subreport-return-value)